Bokeh newer versions does not work with pytrendline, while older versions are unable to install
Im trying to plot trendlines on a graph using pytrendlines, however when i run the code it gives the error

AttributeError: unexpected attribute 'render_mode' to Label, similar
attributes are renderers

It seems that the newer versions of Bokeh are incompatible with the current pytrendline library. So, i go to install a lower version of Bokeh, and I get:
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oovgz6l1\bokeh_959f180cab584b209ab3c3fc3f796765\versioneer.py:419: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\s'
        LONG_VERSION_PY['git'] = '''
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oovgz6l1\bokeh_959f180cab584b209ab3c3fc3f796765\setup.py", line 108, in <module>
          version=versioneer.get_version(),
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oovgz6l1\bokeh_959f180cab584b209ab3c3fc3f796765\versioneer.py", line 1478, in get_version
          return get_versions()["version"]
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oovgz6l1\bokeh_959f180cab584b209ab3c3fc3f796765\versioneer.py", line 1410, in get_versions
          cfg = get_config_from_root(root)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oovgz6l1\bokeh_959f180cab584b209ab3c3fc3f796765\versioneer.py", line 340, in get_config_from_root
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      AttributeError: module 'configparser' has no attribute 'SafeConfigParser'. Did you mean: 'RawConfigParser'?
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.```
So, is my only option to use a lower version of python using conda?
I expect the current version of bokeh to work with pytrendline, as in requirements.txt it says:
bokeh>=2.0.2
But it does not run without error.

I tried running pip install bokeh==3.3.0 (since you didn't specify which version were you trying to install) and it worked on multiple computers. So either this is either an environment specific issue (could be OS, hardware, or even other packages installed), or that the specific version you used contains this error

@oriraisfeld the problem is not installing bokeh==3.30. i can do that fine, but it does not work with pytrendline. so i try pip install bokeh==2.20, and that fails

I assume you mean 2.2.0? I was able to run pip install bokeh==2.2.0 without any issues on OSX with Python 3.10. We have not changed or deleted any releases on PyPI and you can see all the old release history that is avaialble via pip (including 2.2.0) here: https://pypi.org/project/bokeh/#history

Based on this topic looks like this is an issue with versioneer and newer versions of Python (e.g. 3.11 and 3.12) Newer versions of Bokeh no longer rely on versioneer, but for older versions of Bokeh that did use versioneer at the time they were released, it looks like you will have to stick with Python 3.10 and earlier.
